# How to pass a List to function in scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to pass a list to the scala function, transform it and return it.

```
val fun=(lst:List[Int]):List[Int]=>lst+10
error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
```

Comment: You should start by reading some book a tutorial on the basic scala syntax. Not much point in just assembling random characters together and trying to get it to compile. [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_basic_syntax.htm) may be a good starting point.

Comment: Or, if you want to learn Scala 3 - https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You are mixing the definition of the type of `fun` with its implementation.

You probably want something like this:

```scala
val fun: List[Int] => List[Int] = (lst: List[Int]) => lst + 10
```

Then the type of the parameter is actually redundant with the type definition of `fun`, so you can remove it:

```scala
val fun: List[Int] => List[Int] = lst => lst + 10
```

2. You are trying to use the `+` operation/method on a `List[Int]` and a `Int`. There's no such method. If you want to append an item into a list you can use `:+` instead:

```scala
val fun: List[Int] => List[Int] = lst => lst :+ 10
```

More about the available methods on `List` in the official documentation: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: Can I pass list to anonymous function like I can pass single variable?                             val fun=(x:Int)=>x+10                                                                                                                                  I want to do something like                                                                                             
val fun=(x:List[Int])=>x=>x.map(x=>x+10)